# Has anyone noticed recent degradation in Google Knowledge Graph Search API results?

Tags: google-api, google-knowledge-graph

I've been using Google's KGSearch widget to support a quick search box for movie titles, with good results for more than a year until its behavior suddenly became much worse around early this October. Previously it had displayed sensible results incrementally as each letter was typed or a portion of a title was pasted into the search box. Now it frequently fails to produce any results for values that used to work. I don't see any obvious pattern to this flakiness, except that the cases that work and those that don't seem to be pretty consistently reproducible.

For example, "Suspicion" yields no results at all. "Major Dundee" doesn't work, unless you omit the last "e". These are just a couple of numerous examples of such failures. An example that still seems to work properly (sort of) is "Frozen" if you paste the whole value in at once, but if you type it one letter at a time, results vanish and reappear for no apparent reason.

I'd be interested to know if anyone using the KGSearch widget has seen similar problems. Any help from Google support would be greatly appreciated, since this is a very serious problem for me. To confirm this problem, try using the search box at http://www.movie-mine.com/.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, I've identified the apparent cause of this problem. For more info, see my post to Google Webmaster Central Help Forum, [apparent KGSearch widget bug and doc error re the languages config parameter](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/T2wQubhyNFE;context-place=forum/webmasters). Until there is a fix from Google, I will simply work around the issue by omitting use of the languages config param in my web site.